# I'm all around in your daily life - can you guess what I am?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I can help out your friend
>   When there's work going down
>   I can say a lot
>   Without making a sound
>
> I'm made up of parts
>   But they're hard to replace
>   I've improved all our lives
>   I've even been to space
>
> I'm all around you
>   In your daily life
>   If you guess my name
>   It'll be worth the strife

What am I? (Thanks to gstats for that last line :) ).

Ok lot of great ideas but none correct so I'll attempt to give a hint:

> I'm not made up
>  Of circuits and wires
>  And I was around long before
>  The invention of tires

Comment: "it'll be worth the strife"? :p

Comment: How did I not think of that @gstats! Thanks. And thanks for the welcome, @Beastly :)

Comment: Sorry to anyone who may have seen the hint during my fail at using the spoiler tag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it by any chance

> the human hand

I can help out your friend
When there's work going down

> lend a helping hand

I can say a lot
Without making a sound

> sign language, the middle finger, etc...

I'm made up of parts
But they're hard to replace

> kind of self evident in this situation

I've improved all our lives

> evolution is a wonderful thing

I'm all around you
In your daily life

> (almost) everyone has them

If you guess my name
It'll be worth the strife

> *shrug*

Comment: I thought of this too- it definitely fits the first stanza well

Comment: Ding ding ding! Great job! :)

Answer (score 5):

I think it is

> A book

I can help out your friend
When there's work going down

> A book can teach

I can say a lot
Without making a sound

> It doesn't make a noise but tells you a story

I'm made up of parts
But they're hard to replace

> The pages are hard to replace

I've improved all our lives
I've even been to space

> Books have definitely improved life, *especially* sci-fi

I'm all around you
In your daily life

> Books are everywhere

If you guess my name
I'll upvote you for life

> Thanks :P

Comment: Great guess but not what I had in mine.

Answer (score 5):

I think it might be

> a (ballpoint) pen

I can help out your friend
When there's work going down

> Helping write homework or other things

I can say a lot
Without making a sound

> Writing words, telling stories, but silently (unless you're a person who likes to click their pen :p)

I'm made up of parts
But they're hard to replace

> Typically when a pen breaks or runs out of ink you just buy a new one

I've improved all our lives
I've even been to space

> Pens replaced pencils in space - special pens can write in antigravity

I'm all around you
In your daily life

> We use them all the time (I have one right now)

If you guess my name
It'll be worth the strife

> Hopefully it is!

Comment: +1 This is what I was thinking, but I couldn't figure out the "been to space" part. Nice!

Comment: Good guess but not what I had in mind.

Comment: darn it! I was almost positive :) good puzzle @grinch

Answer (score 5):

I think

> Internet

I can help out your friend
When there's work going down

> Stack exchange help us a lot.

I can say a lot
Without making a sound

> Internet is a web of information

I'm made up of parts
But they're hard to replace

> Made up of mainly HTML and Css

I've improved all our lives
I've even been to space

> Any doubt and now ISS astronauts cast a vote from space .Please don't trump.

I'm all around you
In your daily life
If you guess my name
It'll be worth the strife

> Thanks internet

Comment: Good guess but not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Are you a

> Computer?

I can help out your friend
When there's work going down

> Computer can help that out.

I can say a lot
Without making a sound

> Search / Google and the answers are on the screen

I'm made up of parts

> Sure it does

But they're hard to replace

> *Some* parts are hard to replace

I've improved all our lives

> Sure it does again

I've even been to space

> Satellite / space station have computers

I'm all around you
In your daily life

> Yup

If you guess my name
It'll be worth the strife

> Guess computer nowadays do alot more than just 'compute'

Comment: Man, you beat me by 90 seconds...

Comment: @Sid not sure if this is the correct answer thou!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure but I think you're

> A watch

I can help out your friend
When there's work going down

> When your friend's at work they might check their watch often

I can say a lot
Without making a sound

> You use a watch to 'tell' time, hence they say a lot while being fairly or completely quiet!

I'm made up of parts
But they're hard to replace

> A watch has very small moving parts, and it is hard to replace them

I've improved all our lives
I've even been to space

> Spacesuits have watches built into them I think

I'm all around you
In your daily life

> Many people wear watches

If you guess my name
It'll be worth the strife

> A watch!

And the answers to the hint:
I'm not made up
Of circuits and wires

> Although they have small parts, they do not necessarily require electricity to run

And I was around long before
The invention of tires

> Watches were invented before cars

Comment: I was going to answer this but decided not to...

Comment: Had the same idea but more "time" than "watch". Fits the different parts of the riddle quite well.

Answer (score 3):

I guess

> Computer

I can help out your friend

When there's work going down

> A computer helps a lot in completing work/projects...

I can say a lot Without making a sound

> The internet is a valuable tool indeed!

I'm made up of parts But they're hard to replace

> Probably the CPU/UPS.. They can be replaced, but it is expensive..

I've improved all our lives I've even been to space

> The computer has improved our lives. Space probably mentions the huge amount of popularity and reach of the computers..

I'm all around you In your daily life

> Of course it is!

If you guess my name I'll upvote you for life

> Using a computer after all..

Comment: Good guess but not what I have in mind. I added a hint to hopefully steer in  a better direction.